# Passing the values of a form to a PHP script using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having some trouble passing the values of a form to a PHP script using JS.

The PHP script saves the form data into a text file along with some other info (IP, Date/Time) but that is all working fine.

It is most definitely something simple but my limited knowledge of JS is hindering me from solving the issue. Here are the inputs...

```
    <input type="text" id="username"></input>
    <input type="password" id="password"></input>
```

Here is the JS function...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submit').click(function() {

            event.preventDefault(); // prevent PageReLoad

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('POST', 'create_file.php');

            var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            var data = username + ',' + password + ',';

            request.send(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The request need the form data in json format. Try `var data = { username, password };`

Comment: Check out [this MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#example_post) and [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Answer (score 0):

You need Jquery and Ajax

and the syntax is so:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
$.ajax({
         url:"https://yourwebsite.de/file.php",
         type:"POST",
         data: { 
mode: "add", firma: firma, email:email, adresse1: adresse1,adresse2:adresse2 },
         success:function(e){
//answer from php file

         }});
</script>
```

Comment: Why load jquery 2 times?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is lots of examples of how to do this around. You certainly do not need jquery (much less 2 instances of it). Maybe something like this?

```
document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
var form = this;
fetch('create_file.php', {method:'post', body: new FormData(form)})//send the data using fetch
.then(response => response.json()) //get json response
.then(data => console.log(data)); //log the response data
});
```